# Baking with a drip pan

Tags: baking, cake, oven, cookies

I want to bake cookies and croissant but I don't have baking trays. Can I use the drip pan that is removable and metal? It's shiny coated black metal ( not sure which type).

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are talking about something like : https://www.walmart.ca/en/ip/Frigidaire-5304442087-Range-Stove-Oven-Broiler-Pan-1-Blue/PRD2Z84UNVIFLYX

Yeah, you could do it.

If you have parchment paper or silpat silicon baking mat, it would be even better